# "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" impacts normal internet sites

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

When I use the default Compatibility View Settings, internet sites are in Document Mode 7 by default.

The culprit appears to be the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" setting. When I uncheck this, internet sites display appropriately instead of in the legacy document mode.

The odd things is that I'm not on an intranet nor are the sites I visit intranet sites. They're normal internet sites. Why does "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" impact normal internet sites? Is this a bug?

## Developer Tools - Emulation

The developer tools emulation page, for a normal internet site, says that we're in Document mode 7 by default because of intranet compatibility settings. But we're on an internet site? What's up with that?

[image: Developer Tools - Emulation]

## Default Compatibility View Settings

Turning on/off the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" setting impacts normal internet sites. What gives?

[image: Default Compatibility View Settings]

The workaround, of course, is simply to uncheck the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" setting. What I'm looking for here is an explanation of why we need to do this for internet sites.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can engineer this situation by adding a site to your Intranet zone.

- Tools\Internet Options
- Security Tab
- Local Intranet
- Sites
- Advanced

Will lead you to a screen where you can add or remove sites to/from this zone.

Note: There are other ways of adding sites to this list. Some of these ([using Group policy for example](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3421.add-one-url-to-intranet-zone-and-another-url-to-a-trusted-site-zone-through-gpo.aspx)) can cause the screen to become disabled, making it difficult to remove entries.

Note: Initial insight and credit for this answer should go to [@PhilPursglove](http://www.twitter.com/philpursglove/status/718025519057473537)